# Configuring AuthenticationManagerBuilder to use User Repository

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

I am trying to secure Rest APIs using spring boot and JWT. Right now I have been able to piece together pieces of the configuration to get a token generated with a hard coded username and password. I would like my User class and repository to be used instead.

I have been able to hardcode a user here

```
@Override
public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
        .withUser("user")
        .password(passwordEncoder().encode("password"))
        .authorities("ROLE_USER");
}
```

Should I be pointing this to my UserDetailsService? How would I do that?

```
@Service
public class UserSecurityService implements UserDetailsService {

  private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserSecurityService.class);

  @Autowired
  private UserRepository userRepository;

  @Override
  public UserDetails loadUserByUsername (String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    User user = userRepository.findByUsername(username);

    if (null == user) {
        LOG.warn("username not found");
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Username" + username + "not found");
    }
    return user;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `UserDetailsService`, you need `DaoAuthenticationProvider` to handle any authentication requests.

To do so:

```
@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(encoder());
}

// you shouldn't use plain text
@Bean
public PasswordEncoder encoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}
```

above internally configures a `DaoAuthenticationProvider`. Alternatively, you can define a bean to inject:

```
@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
}

@Bean
public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
    DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
    authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(encoder());
    return authProvider;
}
```

Comment: I am getting a 200 for auth so much closer... but no token is generated. I am getting this stacktrace 'com.backend.Entity.User cannot be cast to org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User
 at com.backend.Security.JwtAuthenticationFilter.successfulAuthentication(JwtAuthenticationFilter.java:43)' which is this line  `var user = ((User) authentication.getPrincipal());` in my "JwtAuthenticationFilter.java" class

Comment: That error tells you that your `User` isn't a `UserDetails`, in which case, to resolve name conflict, you need to return `return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword(), user.getAuthorities())`;

Comment: this is assuming your user entity (for the database) has username, password, and authorities...

Comment: Got it. Thank you for the help!